# Javascript using the ceiling function for value less than 1

Tags: javascript, ceil

So, I have a list of items and I want to check how many pages I would need if I want to show , say, 10 items per page

ie

220 should give me 22 pages

134 should give me 14 pages

I am using the ceiling function to get the number of pages

```
var pages = parseInt(items)/10;
alert("pages " +pages);
alert(Math.ceil(pages));
```

The problem which I am having is if I have 7 items, I am expecting it to give me 1 page. However, I don't get any output.
I have noticed that I only get an output if the value for pages from

```
var pages = parseInt(items)/10;
```

is greater than 1 , How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I just tried your code in Chrome's console with `items = 7` and it works fine - I get a second output of `1`. Can you replicate your problem in a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: Is `items` really a number? Try passing the radix parameter.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, doesn't matter - I tried the same code in Firebug and I still get `1`

Comment: @elclanrs yes items is a number

Comment: We need a demo to reproduce the issue, it seems to work fine.

Comment: What does "I don't get any output" mean? Does the alert still *show*? Also, use `parseInt(items, 10)` just to make sure there is no radix fun going on.

Comment: @Bojangles I have just replicated my code in jsbin and I get 1 but not when I run it in firefox

Comment: Then you need to show more code - `items` may not be what you think it is, or something else will be changing your output

Comment: Please post your jsbin link

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies elsewhere. Consider the following `Math.ceil` operations:

```
> Math.ceil(220/10)
22
> Math.ceil(134/10)
14
> Math.ceil(7/10)
1
```

Then look at the operation that you might have handled -- a string version of a number:

```
> Math.ceil(parseInt("7")/10);
1
> Math.ceil(parseInt(" 7")/10);
1
> Math.ceil(parseInt(" 7 ")/10);
1
```

It would appear that `Math.ceil` is providing `1` as expected, unless your value of `7` is malformed.